# Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException +[NSMapTable cde_strongToStrongObjectsMapTable]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, objective-c, webdav, magicalrecord, ensembles

I am currently working on an iPad Application using Objective C language on Xcode version 9.2 and iOS 11.

In this application we are using Ensembles 2 framework with Magical Record for syncing our data between 2 iPads and WebDAV as backend.

The framework successfully syncs data when we install the app on real iPad device directly through Xcode or when we test on simulator iPad's. But after we archive the app and send it to users through distribution it crashes on launch. And through crashalytics logs we have below information:

```
CDEPersistentStoreEnsemble.m line 140
-[CDEPersistentStoreEnsemble initWithEnsembleIdentifier:persistentStoreURL:persistentStoreOptions:managedObjectModelURL:cloudFileSystem:localDataRootDirectoryURL:]


CDESaveMonitor.m line 33 
-[CDESaveMonitor initWithStorePath:]

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
+[NSMapTable cde_strongToStrongObjectsMapTable]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1b429eb18
```

In the app we do have -ObjC set in the Targets- Build Settings- Other Linker Flags

Comment: What is `cde_strongToStrongObjectsMapTable`? Is this a category method of some sort? Are you sure you're including it in your release build?

Comment: Seems like category methods not being linked for the release build. Do you have -Objc linker flag in the Other Linker Flags in build settings for release configuration?